# Programming Interview Example

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
class string {

public:

    string( char const* t ) : s(t) {}

    ~string() { delete s; }

    char const* c_str() const { return s; }

private:

    char const* s;

};
```

I was asked what are the memory problems with the above, now I don't generally look at memory don't even program much in C, so I had no idea, now from what little I know of C, I thought that the problem is that there isn't explicit memory allocation and `const *` since wrong but, I am putting the question here to see what other think.

Comment: I think the destructor may need to be virtual as well, in case someone subclasses `string`.

Comment: @i_am_jorf Possibly, but when deleting a derived class object through a base class pointer, (string in this case), the base class dtor would still be called. The derived classes' dtor wouldn't be called in that case.

Comment: Ah okay, fair enough.  It's been a while.  :)  Mainly my suspicion was that the interviewer was looking for a mention of that.

Comment: The real question here is: What is right about this class? Ans: Nothing.

Answer (score 4):

From the class definition it is not clear who is responsible for deleting the pointer. Also what to do if the argument of the constructor is a pointer to the first character of a string literal. In this case using delete (more precisely delete[]) simply is wrong.

Also it is not clear whether  it is a pointer to a single character and delete has to be used or it is a pointer to the first character of an array and delete [] has to be used.

P.S. I always wonder why some programmers as for example you try to resolve some assignments in an interview. An interview is not an exam. If you are asked to resolve some assignment then it means that you are dealing with idiots that do not respect you. **Never** do any assignment in an interview.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last paragraph?

Comment: @hek2mgl The class is named string however there is used operator delete instead of delete[]. So it is not clear whether it is a typo or the class keeps a pointer to a single character.

Comment: I meant the last paragraph. I just wonder why an (short) assignment should be a bad idea in an interview and I can't see why this would express less respect. From my own experience it is quite usual and I appreciate this. If companies talking only about opportunities, money and vacation this is not a good sign at all.

Comment: @hek2mgl Why shall somebody do your assignments?! Maybe you come to my home and mop a floor? Why do you invite to an interview programmees about their qualification you can say nothing? Are you yourself ready to perform assignments of your interviewee? Maybe he should substitute you in the job because his qualification is higher?

Comment: I'm willing to get you but I still fail. Code says more than 1000 words. Unless you hire a well-known top programmer who has committed to various open source projects, how will you know that the guy can write good code? (Even under pressure) Note that 99.99999% of candidates aren't well known top programmers.

Comment: @hek2mgl If you come in any firm you will see that there are many children, wifes, friends of whose who close to the boss. Assignments are given only to whose who is not your friend  or relative because it is a pity to give money to unknown people. All firm such as IBM, Microsoft are full of very low qualified programmers. Can you say what interview did they pass?!

Comment: @hek2mgl My professor of mathematics  said that it is enough to a student to say a pair of first words and it is clear for him whether the student knows subject or not, For me it is the same in programming.

Comment: I agree that so many - even well known - companies are full of low quality programmers. However, not all! I can only say don't give up the search! I almost did, now I am quite happy :) .. And I had to do multiple assignments through the application process. Through the way how they gave feedback to the assignments and how they answered my questions I already had a good impression about them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76252/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks, but I am sorry this question is not interesting to me.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor doesn't allocate any memory for its argument; it just saves the pointer. When the destructor gets called, it will deallocate memory that someone else allocated.

Answer (score 2):

There are several (memory) issues here:

1. The constructor only makes a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of *t* and stores it in *s*
2. (Arising from 1.): The destructor frees memory allocated by someone else (or worse, invoked UB if *s* doesn't point to the beginning of a memory block, or a string literal.